# how do we connect to command prompt with C# script

Tags: c#

With the help of C# how we could connect to command prompt & pickup inputs over there & re-use or call in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't, it's impossible. Nobody other than Jon Skeet has ever connected to command prompt to pickup inputs, over there.

Comment: Wow, so much wrong with this question. First of all C# is a compiled language - not a script. Secondly, C#, Java, or Ruby? Pick one. Finally, what the hell are you asking? Are you just trying to [Create a C# Console Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78.aspx)?  Or are you asking about something like the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) in Visual Studio?

Comment: @DeeMac and **even Google** refuses to provide results when searching for such... :) (after all, Google is just a cheap frontend to JonSkeet, if I'm right)

Comment: @ppeterka66 - indeed. It doesn't surprise me that google yields no results from JonSkeet on this topic, he's often very reluctant to disclose his C# knowledge. He keeps his cards close to his chest, that one. I bet he's using C# to connect to command prompt to pickup inputs right as we speak.

Answer (score 2):

Use ScriptCS. Read about it at http://scriptcs.net.